# how to change download sources used for building netbeans-apache?

Tags: installation, java, netbeans, repository, maven

I have followed this guide from netbeans: [build from source](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/nb112.html#_building_from_source)

Unfortunately on running ant build, as it tries to download from maven central repository it uses an url that seems outdated, the new url appers to be metioned on [new url](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central). Where do I make the changes, or could it be a problem with my system?

error (some urls omitted):

```
Buildfile: /home/teste/Downloads/netbeans-11.2-source/build.xml

-jdk-pre-preinit:

-jdk-preinit:

-jdk-warn:

-jdk-presetdef-basic:

-jdk-default:

-jdk-init:

-load-build-properties:

bootstrap:
[downloadbinaries] Could not download 16398550402B27F81CD0D508CEF54B3E47A4A6DA-apache-rat-0.12.jar to /home/teste/.hgexternalcache/16398550402B27F81CD0D508CEF54B3E47A4A6DA-apache-rat-0.12.jar: java.io.IOException: Cannot connect to http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/rat/apache-rat/0.12/apache-rat-0.12.jar


BUILD FAILED
/home/teste/Downloads/netbeans-11.2-source/nbbuild/build.xml:71: Failed to download binaries - see log message for the detailed reasons.
```

nmap also complains on not finding a target on this maven url as well,so it seems to really be gone.

either way, if it is possible to get the files in a way that they get used by the build it also would solve my issues

Answer (score 0):

vim ./nbbuild/antsrc/org/netbeans/nbbuild/extlibs/DownloadBinaries.java

163     private byte[] mavenFile(MavenCoordinate mc) throws IOException {
164         String cacheName = mc.toMavenPath();
165         File local = new File(new File(new File(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")), ".m2"), "repository"), ca    cheName.replace('/', File.separatorChar));
166         final String url;
167         if (local.exists()) {
168             url = local.toURI().toString();
169         } else {
170             url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" + cacheName;
171         }
172         URL u = new URL(url);
173         return downloadFromServer(u);
174     }

change line 170